# April Fools Jokes

Tags: code-challenge, popularity-contest

Figure out how to mess up another programmer's project by making a subtle, hard to find (but "harmless") "bug". (Double quotes FTW!)

Try to keep them short; `shorter ~= subtle`.

---

For example:

```
#define true false
```

---

Don't actually *destroy* the code *directly*. For example, from this:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
```

To:

```
for(size_t *i = new size_t; ++i; delete i)
```

Or even:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i <= 10; ++i)
```

Is *not* OK. If a language actually allows you to change `<` to `<=` without changing that code "directly", then it's alright. (You know what I mean. Deleting all the code is just

---

### Voting

Up vote the most original/creative/subtle solutions.

On Mother's Day (May 8, 2011), the most up voted answer will be chosen as the winner.

Comment: They [did this on TheDailyWTF](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Disgruntled-Bomb.aspx) about a month and a half ago.

Comment: My favourite was setting String.Empty to another value :)

Comment: Subjective? http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/305/what-makes-winning-criteria-objective

Comment: I don’t understand why “number of votes” is considered a subjective criterion. One would have thought that most people can read the vote-counts and determine, objectively, which is highest?

Comment: Deleting all the code is just??  I don't think so :)

Comment: It's just because it's impossible to do in most languages, I think... but still a bit of a silly statement ;)

Comment: @Timwi: "Number of votes" is subjective because many people use subjective criteria to decide whether to upvote, downvote, or neither. It's not "indisputable".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
#define if(x) if(random(100) > 0 && (x))
```

Comment: For C, I think you'd need to say `random() % 100`.

Comment: No... not with `stdlib.h`.

Answer (score 7):

### Haskell

```
module UnsafePrelude where

import Prelude hiding ((.), (+), (-), sum, map, foldl)
import qualified Prelude as P

import Unsafe.Coerce

-- disallow (f . g . h)
infix 9 .
(.) = (P..)

-- Make arithmetic a bit more exciting.
-- These actually work correctly for trivial Int and Integer cases,
-- at least in GHC 6.12.1 on x86.
(+), (-) :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a
(+) = unsafeCoerce ((P.+) :: Float -> Float -> Float)
(-) = unsafeCoerce ((P.-) :: Float -> Float -> Float)

sum :: (Num a, Num b) => [a] -> b
sum = unsafeCoerce (P.sum :: [Float] -> Float)

-- Make map a little less type-safe.
map :: (a -> b) -> [c] -> [b]
map   = unsafeCoerce P.map

-- Make foldl associate the wrong way, but still have the same type.
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
foldl f = foldr (flip f)
```

Answer (score 6):

### GolfScript

```
1:
```

Note there is a space after the colon. This assigns the value `1` to the space character. All further code that uses the space for readability will find unexpected extra ones on its stack!

Alternatively,

```
0:1
```

assigns the value `0` to the character `1`.

Comment: Of course, I'm not quite sure why you'd be coding in GolfScript for any 'project' other than golf... :)

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby

```
class Fixnum
    alias add +
    def + (n)
        add n.add 1
    end
end
```

And now, like in *1984*...

```
(33):0>  2 + 2 == 5
>>> true
(36):0>
```

Comment: I prefer this: `class Fixnum; alias - +; end`

Comment: @Matma Rex: That's a bit easier to notice...